# Hibernate JPA with SQL Server - Joins are case sensitive

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to test joins in Hibernate JPA with MS SQL Server. By default, MS SQL Server is case insensitive.

When I tried to do join on a non-primary key, which is varchar in Hibernate JPA, the result are coming when join matches value with match case i.e. if the case is not matching, result set is not including that particular record.

I have reproduced it as part of my Test Application. Some sample Code is here. I have two tables - Employee and Skill and records for testing are -

```
insert into Employee (EmpID, EmpUniqueID, Name) values (1, 'bradpi', 'Brad Pitt');

insert into Skill (SkillID, SkillName, EmpUniqueID) values (1, 'CrimeSkill', 'bradpi')
insert into Skill (SkillID, SkillName, EmpUniqueID) values (2, 'ComedySkill', 'bradpi')
insert into Skill (SkillID, SkillName, EmpUniqueID) values (5, 'OtherSkill', 'BRADPI')
```

I am trying to do join with the column "EmpUniqueID" and the last record is having value with upper case i.e. "BRADPI". This particular record is not coming in Hibernate JPA, but the query generated by Hibernate is running properly in SQL Server and returning all three records.

Employee class

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "getEmployeeByUniqueID", query = "select e from Employee e where e.empUniqueID = :empUniqueID")
})
@Table(name = "Employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "EmpID")
    private int empID;

    @Column(name = "EmpUniqueID")
    private String empUniqueID;

    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "employee")
    private Set<Skill> skills = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Skill class (relationship variable) -

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "EmpUniqueID", referencedColumnName = "EmpUniqueID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Employee employee;
```

Querying using Named Query -

```
Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("getEmployeeByUniqueID", Employee.class);
query.setParameter("empUniqueID", empUniqueID);
Employee employee = (Employee) query.getSingleResult();
```

Employee skills list is returning only two skills for "bradpi" search. Ideally it should return 3 skills.

Please let me know if there is any way to make it case insensitive in settings as SQL Server is case insensitive.

---

Updating with generated SQLs.
Generated SQLs are -

```
select employee0_.EmpID as EmpID1_0_0_, skills1_.SkillID as SkillID1_1_1_, employee0_.EmpUniqueID as EmpUniqu2_0_0_, employee0_.Name as Name3_0_0_, skills1_.EmpUniqueID as EmpUniqu2_1_1_, skills1_.SkillName as SkillNam3_1_1_, skills1_.EmpUniqueID as EmpUniqu2_0_0__, skills1_.SkillID as SkillID1_1_0__ from Employee employee0_ left outer join Skill skills1_ on employee0_.EmpUniqueID=skills1_.EmpUniqueID where employee0_.EmpUniqueID=?
select employee0_.EmpID as EmpID1_0_0_, employee0_.EmpUniqueID as EmpUniqu2_0_0_, employee0_.Name as Name3_0_0_ from Employee employee0_ where employee0_.EmpUniqueID=?
select employee0_.EmpID as EmpID1_0_0_, employee0_.EmpUniqueID as EmpUniqu2_0_0_, employee0_.Name as Name3_0_0_ from Employee employee0_ where employee0_.EmpUniqueID=?
select employee0_.EmpID as EmpID1_0_0_, employee0_.EmpUniqueID as EmpUniqu2_0_0_, employee0_.Name as Name3_0_0_ from Employee employee0_ where employee0_.EmpUniqueID=?
```

I have ran above SQLs by changing "?" to value "bradpi". When I run in SQL Server, all the SQLs are returning result. First SQL is returning 3 records and others are returning 1 record.

I have tested multiple times by updating table in backend. When I change the value of EmpUniqueID in Skill table to uppercase i.e. "BRADPI", Hibernate is not bringing this particular Skill record but SQL Server query result is brining.

Comment: look at the SQL invoked by the JPA provider. All it will do is create some SQL and invoke it, and if, as you say, all is case insensitive, then all should be fine.

Comment: @Neil, Thanks for the answer. I have already looked into SQL. When I run the SQL in the SQL Server, the results are coming with 3 skills. It is not coming in Hibernate JPA only. I tested this by changing the case and running program multiple times and when the case matches, hibernate is bringing the result else not. Seems like there is some programming to populate Entity object relation as i am doing join with non primary string parameter.

Comment: Sure you looked at the SQL, but people here can't see them. Update your question with such basic info.

Comment: Hello :) I have the same issue with MySQL 5.7. Is there any idea how to solve the issue above?

Comment: have you tried this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70126301/13061224