# How to specify ignore case in JPA @JoinColumn when I am using two tables entity

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

I have two entities. Account entity and B_Account.

In Account entity I am joining table like below.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=eger)
@JoinColumn(name = "a_type")
private B_Account b_Account;
```

Now the issue is `a_type` attribute value in  Account is "ganesh" and in B_Account is "GANESH".

This is the reason I am not getting the data when I used `findBy(B_Account)` using repository method.

How can I join the tables above so that it can ignore the small and uppercase?

Comment: That means you don't have a foreign key in the database? You should clean up the data and introduce a foreign key that this cannot happen

Comment: No I have primary as well as foreign key. I just want to case ignore in @joincolumn. 
 -->Now the issue is a_type attribute value in Account is "ganesh" and in B_Account is "GANESH". This is the reason I am not getting the data when i used findBy(B_Account) using repository method.

Now I want to do something in joining the table above so that it can ignore the small and uppercase.

Comment: Yes but if you have a foreign key between a_type and b_account then it must have the same case

Answer (score 0):

You can try `@JoinFormula` That's a Hibernate proprietary annotation that doesn't exist in JPA.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=eger)
@JoinFormula(name = "lower(b_account) = a_type")
private B_Account b_Account;
```

I cannot test it so please try it out.

Documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-JoinFormula

Comment: What is acc_type?

Comment: acc_type is table column .